# How can I stop a user from deleting emails? - Emails hosted on cPanel

Tags: email, cpanel, filtering, email-accounts

Just wondering how can I stop a user from deleting emails on a mailbox that is being hosted on cPanel?

I have already created another mailbox that will auto-forward incoming emails - but I would like to keep a copy of the sent emails as well

Any ideas? :)

Comment: What e-mail server are you using??

Comment: I'll assume the user is aware that you're keeping copies of incoming and outgoing emails... You can set [global email filters](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/68Docs/Global+Email+Filters) in cPanel instead of forwarding, however that only applies to _incoming_ emails. For _outgoing_  emails, you'll need to add an [Exim system filter](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Customize+the+Exim+System+Filter+File). Note they can still use another email client and SMTP to send email with the same email address however, which would bypass cPanel altogether.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent a/any user to perform any actions on a mailbox, just change the user's rights on that mailbox.

Comment: Can you expand on this at all? How would you do this through cPanel or command line?